# What should I remove from my android project for security reasons, before uploading it to a public github repo?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, apk

I have published the app on the android store, however, I wish to upload it to github for my portfolio. I know that I need to remove the keystore and compiled resources are not usefull. What else should I remove?

Comment: Also you should move any APIs keys

Comment: also mention credits to appropriate library/module/API developer if you have used any

Comment: is the applicationId in the build.gradle sensitive info?